# Error(4,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AS"

Tags: oracle

What is wrong with the following function I am trying to create and compile?

I get this error code and I'm unsure exactly what is wrong with it.

```
Error(4,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AS" when expecting one of the following:     return
```

Code:

```
create or replace FUNCTION BOD_FM_FSCS_A_Data(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    p_ExclusionsOnly NUMBER DEFAULT 0 )
AS
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @ATable
  SELECT DISTINCT SCVID,
    Title,
    Forename1,
    Forename2,
    Forename3,
    CASE
      WHEN CompanyName IS NULL
      OR CompanyName    =''
      THEN Surname
      ELSE CompanyName
    END AS Surname ,
    PreviousName,
    NI_No,
    PassportNo,
    OtherNational_ID,
    OtherNational_ID_No ,
    CompanyNo,
    DateOfBirth
  FROM DIM_FM_FSCS_Customer customer
  INNER JOIN DIM_FM_FSCS_CustomerAccLink cal
  ON cal.FSCSCustomerLink=customer.ID
  INNER JOIN DIM_FM_FSCS_Account acc
  ON acc.ID              =cal.FSCSAccountLink
  AND ( (p_ExclusionsOnly=1
  AND acc.ExclusionCode <>'')
  OR (p_ExclusionsOnly   =0
  AND acc.ExclusionCode  = ''));
  RETURN
END;
```

Comment: `@ATable` is an invalid table name. You need double quotes for that : `"@ATable"`

Comment: That isn't whats causing the error

Comment: Functions need a RETURN clause in the CREATE statement (at the top).

Comment: And you don't need both AS and IS.

Comment: So you changed the question after I provided the help you needed to solve the first question...Well played

Comment: You can refine a question but not completely change the direction of the problem - this site isn't really intended to be an iterative debug helper. The code you pasted also looks very wrong at the top - you might want to fix that.

Comment: Changing the question (even the title) to ask about another error after the first error was fixed is borderline abusive. Do it again and I will flag it for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error speaks for itself:

> Error(4,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AS" when expecting one
>   of the following:     return

Remove the AS and define what the function RETURN

```
create or replace FUNCTION BOD_FM_FSCS_A_Data(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    p_ExclusionsOnly NUMBER DEFAULT 0 )
RETURN NUMBER....
```

Here's an example from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm)

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_bal(acc_no IN NUMBER) 
   RETURN NUMBER 
   IS acc_bal NUMBER(11,2);
   BEGIN 
      SELECT order_total 
      INTO acc_bal 
      FROM orders 
      WHERE customer_id = acc_no; 
      RETURN(acc_bal); 
    END;
/
```